# How to make a TextBox same width as parent view

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have tried both with `width="auto"` and `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`, but both of them do not give me the result I want. It seems that the width of the text box is always based on the size of the header of the text box. Why?

This is the XMAL:

```
<ListView Width="auto">
    <TextBox Width="auto"
             Header="Please Enter Email Address"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             Header="Please Enter Email address"/>
</ListView>
```

This is the output:

[image]

This is what I am looking for:

[image]

I get the above screenshot by setting the width to a fixed values. But I want to find a way to let the text box automatically resize base on the parent view (for example a `ListView` in this case).

---

**Edit:**

Based on Alan's answer, it works great in portrait mode. But still not taking the full width in landscape.

```
<ListView x:Name="lv" Width="auto">
    <TextBox Width="{Binding ElementName=lv, Path=ActualWidth}"
     Header="Please Enter Email Address"/>
    <TextBox Width="{Binding ElementName=lv, Path=ActualWidth}"
     Header="Please Enter Email address"/>
</ListView>
```

Left Image: portrait mode; Right Image: landscape mode. 
[image]
[image]

---

**Edit 2:**

I notice that both @Alan's answer and @Jogy's answer are both okay if the parent view is `<Page>`. However, if the parent view is `<ContentDialog>`, neither of them works. As a matter of fact, if the parent view is `<Page>`, simple using this `<TextBox Width="auto"/>` will works as expected. There may be obvious thing about Windows Phone I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the Width to its parent control's ActualWidth like below:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv" Width="auto">
    <TextBox Width="{Binding ElementName=lv, Path=ActualWidth}"
     Header="Please Enter Email Address"/>
    <TextBox Width="{Binding ElementName=lv, Path=ActualWidth}"
     Header="Please Enter Email address"/>
</ListView>
```

**[Update]**

Because the actualwidth property will not be updated on orientation change. Let's try a different way:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="StretchedListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StretchedListViewItem}" x:Name="lv" Width="auto">
        <TextBox Width="auto"
         Header="Please Enter Email Address"/>
        <TextBox Width="auto"
         Header="Please Enter Email address"/>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

**[Update 2]**

***[Why]***

This is a very interesting topic, it's about how to override the Control's default style.

Let me explain why we cannot make our previous solution for Page to work in ContentDialog. It's because the ContentDialog has the following default style in generic.xaml(you can find in the windows phone 8.1 sdk):

```
<!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog -->
  <!-- NOTE: Because this type didn't ship in WinBlue, we use a prefix to trick the
         XAML parser to not only consider its own type table when parsing, even though
         this exists in a jupiter-owned namespace. -->
  <Style TargetType="controls:ContentDialog">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:ContentDialog">
          <Border x:Name="Container">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                <VisualState x:Name="Portrait" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPanel" EnableDependentAnimation="True">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogContentLandscapeWidth}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="HorizontalAlignment" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPanel">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Left" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
              </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement" 
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                <Border FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}">
                  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{ThemeResource ContentDialogTitleMinHeight}" />
                      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{ThemeResource ContentDialogContentMinHeight}" />
                      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonsMinHeight}" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="Title"
                                    Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogTitleMargin}"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}"
                                    FontSize="{StaticResource TextStyleExtraLargeFontSize}"
                                    FontFamily="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                                    FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      FontSize="{StaticResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}"
                                      FontFamily="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                                      Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogContentMargin}"
                                      Grid.Row="1"
                                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <Border x:Name="Button1Host" Padding="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButton1HostPadding}" Grid.Row="2" />
                    <Border x:Name="Button2Host" Padding="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButton2HostPadding}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
                  </Grid>
                </Border>
              </Border>
            </Grid >
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

The interest things which cause the difference from Page:

1. the margins of title and content were set to(suggest to  keep it):

   ContentDialogTitleMargin 19,33.5,19,0

   ContentDialogContentMargin 19,16.5,19,0

2: the width in Landscape mode was set to:

```
...
<x:Double x:Key="ContentDialogContentLandscapeWidth">400</x:Double>
...
```

3. the HorizontalAlignment in Landscape mode was set to:
   Value="Left"

***[Solution]***

In addition to the steps I provided before(just need to change the Page.Resources to ContentDialog.Resources), we need to do the following steps

To solve the issue, add the following  into your App.xaml:

```
   <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FullScreenContentDialogStyle" TargetType="ContentDialog">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">

                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentDialog">
                        <Border x:Name="Container">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Portrait" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPanel" EnableDependentAnimation="True">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Auto" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="HorizontalAlignment" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPanel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Stretch" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                                    <Border FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}">
                                        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{ThemeResource ContentDialogTitleMinHeight}" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{ThemeResource ContentDialogContentMinHeight}" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonsMinHeight}" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <ContentControl x:Name="Title"
                                                            Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogTitleMargin}"
                                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}"
                                                            FontSize="{StaticResource TextStyleExtraLargeFontSize}"
                                                            FontFamily="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                                                            FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />


                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                              FontSize="{StaticResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}"
                                                              FontFamily="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                                                              Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogContentMargin}"
                                                              Grid.Row="1"
                                                              Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                                            <Border x:Name="Button1Host" Padding="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButton1HostPadding}" Grid.Row="2" />
                                            <Border x:Name="Button2Host" Padding="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButton2HostPadding}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid >
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>


    </Application.Resources>
```

And here is the CustomContentDialog.xaml:

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="CSharpWP81.CustomContentDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CSharpWP81"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="DIALOG TITLE"
    PrimaryButtonText="sign in"  
    SecondaryButtonText="cancel"
    PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
    SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    Style="{StaticResource FullScreenContentDialogStyle}">

    <ContentDialog.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="StretchedListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ContentDialog.Resources>


    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StretchedListViewItem}" x:Name="lv">
            <TextBox Width="auto"
         Header="Please Enter Email Address"/>
            <TextBox Width="auto"
         Header="Please Enter Email address"/>
        </ListView>

    </StackPanel>

</ContentDialog>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This actually works in portrait mode. however, if I rotate the device, it is still taking only part of the width of the screen. Any thought about that?

Comment: I updated my answer. I after that I noticed Jogy has provided the right direction.

Comment: Hello Alan. Thanks for the edit again! I notice that my parent view `<ContentDialog>` instead of `<Page>`. Therefore, I changed `<Page.Resources>` to <ContentDialog.Resources>. But I don't see any effects at all. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What can I say. I can't believe such a small feature required that many of lines of code! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of binding the Width, try to add this below the opening ListView tag:

```
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

[UPDATE]

Apparently there is a problem with ContentDialog and landscape mode. 
Check this thread:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6c8ad10c-3b27-4991-9a5a-8cb15b338709/contentdialog-behavior-in-landscape-orientation?forum=wpdevelop

If you set the background color of the List to Red, you will see that the whole List is cropped when the phone is in Landscape mode.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your reply when editing my reply. You are on the right direction.

Comment: Hello, Joggy, thanks for the answer. However, I tried it out and it is not working though. I think this may only works if the parent view is `<Page>`? Maybe the fact that my parent view is a `<ContentDialog>` is causing the problem?